# Edit a User with Cloud Code javascript and iOS Parse SDK

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, parse-platform, swift3

I'm developing an iOS app with Parse SDK hosted on back4app, my app in the back4app dashboard hosts a main.js file in Cloud Code that sends push notifications, it gets called by code and it works fine.

Now I've added a **`blockuser.js`** file in my Cloud Code, such file should edit the `isBlocked` column (of type Boolean) of a specific user in _User class and set it to `true`, here's the code I use:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("blockUser", function(request, response) {

    var userId = request.params.userId,

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    user.set('isBlocked', true);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });

});
```

Here's the Swift code I wrote to call that function:

```
let request = ["userId" : userPointer.objectId!] as [String : Any]

PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "blockUser", withParameters: request as [String : Any], block: { (results, error) in
        if error == nil {
           print ("\(userPointer["username"]!) has been blocked!")
           // error in cloud code
        } else {
            print ("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
}})
```

The `Xcode` console prints out this message:

```
[Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.14.2)
```

In fact, that `blockUser` function doesn't work at all.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong in the `.js` or swift code?

Answer (score 1):

After a few attempts, I've figured it out, here's the function I've added in my main.js file in Cloud Code:

```
// BLOCK A USER  ----------------------------------------
Parse.Cloud.define("blockUser", function(request, response) {

    var userId = request.params.userId;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    user.set('isBlocked', true);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true } ).then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

And here's the Swift 3 code to call `blockUser` function:

```
    let request = [
        "userId" : userPointer.objectId!
    ] as [String : Any]

    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "blockUser", withParameters: request as [String : Any], block: { (results, error) in
     if error == nil {
          print ("\(userPointer["username"]!) has been blocked!")
     // error
     } else {
         print ("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
   }})
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you did not reload your main.js (file where you write cloud code functions) on server